# Unexpected animation when changing Layout Margins on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Since I upgraded to Jelly Bean 4.1.1 I have an unexpected sliding animation whenever changing the margins of any RelativeLayout programmatically. This happens if for example I change margins from (10, 10, 200, 200) to (20, 20, 220, 220), so meaning that because of the margins the layout will actually change position.

The model I used for development is a Samsung Galaxy SIII.

Is this something new that Google implemented on this version? or something specific from Samsung? I can't find on the API any reference on this.

Anyone knows how to override this sliding animation which I haven't in fact set at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.0 there is a LayoutTransition property android:animateLayoutChanges, that you can set on a view. See here [Animating Layout Changes](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html)

Strange that it would be doing it automatically without you having set it. Maybe that is default behaviour on the S3 if not explicitly set.

Try setting `android:animateLayoutChanges="false"` in the parent view in your activity's xml layout?